# Save an image to a specified path with default filename without SaveFileDialog in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

A WPF button opens a file dialog to open an image and display it in an image control

I want to use another button event to open the image in another app, is this possible?

Comment: Whats type of your image in C#? System.Drawing.Image? Whats object you should save to file?

Comment: "I have tried the below but no file was saved". Sure, there is no code that would save a file.

Comment: You should to save 'imagebox.Source' object to file as image?

Comment: @Clemens you marked as duplicate but that question does not answer mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    byte[] data;
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imagebox.Source as BitmapImage));
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(ms);
        data = ms.ToArray();
    }

    if (data != null)
    {
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use a dialog you could just specify the file name in a string variable:

```
byte[] data;
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imagebox.Source as BitmapImage));
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}

if (data != null)
{ 
    const string filename = @"c:\test\1.jpg";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
}
```

Comment: Note that instead of encoding to a MemoryStream and then writing the MemoryStream's buffer to a file, you could as well directly encode into a FileStream.

Comment: @mm8 - this done the trick, thank you. However, I would like it to overwrite any existing files with the same name, is this possible?

Comment: The WriteAllBytes method should overwrite the file if it exists by default. So my code should work as is.

Comment: @mm8 I think I have this working, but if I wanted 'encoder.Frames.Add...' to allow null values is this possible

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but it makes no sense to add null values to the Frames collection of a BitmapEncoder.